# Create PDF with Table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, cordova, documentation-generation, jspdf

I'm currently creating a phonegap app that lets you  input Data and then creates a PDF with that data.
The Input is done, but I can't find anything to make a PDF with Javascript. So far I only found jsPDF, but that doesn't support tables.
The App must work offline.
Does someone have an Idea?

Comment: You could probably use pdf.fromHTML() to create tables, but then you would have to generate a HTML table first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Bytescout PDF Generator SDK for Javascript* might come in handy: http://bytescout.com/products/developer/pdfgeneratorsdkjs/index.html

Ensure that browser inconsistencies for your targeted devices are taken into account.

Answer (score 10):

I wanted to use jsPDF to generate tables so I made a table plugin for it. Check it out! [jspdf-autotable](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable) It has all the features I was looking for in a table plugin.

- Auto width (100% of page width or only as much as required)
- Multiple pages
- Custom headers and footers
- Multiple tables on the same page
- Custom styling
- [Examples](https://simonbengtsson.github.io/jsPDF-AutoTable/)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org) let's you easily create tables.

It can automatically repeat headers, supports column/row spans and comes with a lot of other options.

There's an example for tables in [the playground](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html)

Comment: Please [indicate in your answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) that you are the creator of pdfmake. Otherwise it looks like astroturfing.

Comment: No other js lib support nested tables to be exported to pdf. `pdfmake` is awesome.

Comment: Ya the auto repeating feature is really awesome, but sometime its not working perfectly.The repeated header overlaps the content. @bartekp do you know how to stop auto repeat table header ?

Answer (score 4):

jsPDF provide good support for tables using [jsPDF-AutoTable](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable) plugin.

jsPDF and pdfmake are two javascript libraries widely used to generate pdf. I have used both and would like to share few points i observed:

**jsPDF**

1. Performance is really good. I would able to generate PDF of 2000
   pages in 5-6 seconds.
2. It doesn't support utf-8 format i.e. you won't be able to render pdf
   in chinese, turkish and other languages.
3. It doesn't support row break and table inside table.

**pdfmake**

1. Performace is good if you are generating pdf of less than 40 pages. Performance degrade exponentially if you generate larged pdf. Almost kill the browser.
2. Support utf-8 format.
3. Support row break and table inside table.
4. Easy to use.

You can make wise decision based on your requirement.

Comment: Note that jsPDF has now added support for utf-8 fonts and that jspdf-autotable now has supports for table inside tables and row breaks.